# Android Button KeyDown - KeyUp | Different Button Events

Tags: android, events, button

I have a easy question about devoloping android app. 
Question is diffrent type of button.
For example, when my finger on the button, music is play but when my finger up to button music is stopped. How can i do this. İt's probably diffrent type of button event's but I don't know. 
I google ıt but I find anything.
PS: I can starting, stopping process on normal button. But i can't do like this.
PS2: When I search on forums somebody recommend to using MotionEvent but I  guess my motionEvent codes are broken.

```
play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{           
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                 m1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.be);
                m1.start();
                m1.setLooping(true);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                m1.stop();
                m1.release();

                break;                      
            default:
                break;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing m1 before your switch statement?

Comment: Let me try. you mention about this ?  m1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.be); (I understand little diffucult because my english so bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay okay ı got it. This is my answer.

```
play1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {





    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                m1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.be);
                m1.start();
                m1.setLooping(true);
            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
           m1.stop();
           m1.release();

            break;
        }
        // tell the system that we handled the event but a further processing is required
        return false;

    }


});
```