# Time since button released

Tags: android, timer, delay

I am trying to calculate the length of time that has elapsed since a button was released. I understand how to calculate this by waiting for the user to interact with the application again but i would like to be able to wait a fixed period - say 2 seconds - before a method is called or another event is triggered.

I am not sure how i can achieve this - is there a way of doing this without waiting for the user to press the button again?

Comment: check out this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376374/android-button-keydown-keyup-different-button-events

Comment: So that we're clear, you'd like the following to happen: User releases a button, start a timer, ALL UI events are blocked until the fixed period of time elapses. So all other taps, button presses, etc are blocked. Essentially, to the user, it would be like your app froze and stopped working for 2 seconds or whatever the time period. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It is a Morse code application i am working on as a small project to help me learn android - when the user has entered the Morse symbol then if the time elapsed since the button is pressed is say 0.5 of a second then i know the user wants to start a new letter as opposed to staying on the current letter. I am not sure if all UI events are to be blocked as the user may want to exit the activity.

Comment: if you wanna execute code 2 seconds after a button click, just use Handler.postDelayed() inside the click listener

Answer (score 0):

Hey perfect_comment for this kind of timed task there is a few things you could do one of which is using ScheduledExecutorService this will allow you to set up a runnable to do some task at a fixed interval. In your onCreate method you would declare the shceduler like this

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

`ScheduledFuture<?> future;`

then tell your your scheduler to run some future task like this

```
 `future = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(mRunnable, 1, DISCOVERY_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

where runnable is a Runnable you have defined

```
 mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { //printer has been found execute runnable
            //your task code
        }
    };
```